# How can I make JSON objects based on the ID of the containers I create and fill out

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Problem: my JSON isn't practical and I just feel I am going to encounter problems (already encountering them). As you can see my JSON looks odd, but somehow it's valid JSON (checked with JSONLint). I have input fields which are in containers with their own unique id (they increment). I was wondering if it's possible to send the data inserted into the input fields together so when I fetch it, it will stay together.

how my JSON looks like right now:

```
{
"main_object": {
    "id": "new",
    "formData": {
        "language": "nl_NL",
        "getExerciseTitle": "ExampleForStackOverflow",
        "question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[0": "ExampleForStackOverflow",
        "Syllablescounter[0": "Example",
        "Syllablescounter[1": "Example1",
        "question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[1": "SecondExampleForStackOverflow",
        "Syllablescounter[2": "Second",
        "Syllablescounter[3": "Example"
    }
  }
}
```

what I am looking and hoping to achieve: source: Luiz Carloz (Thank you very much).

```
{ "main_object": 
  {
  "id": "new",
  "formData": [
    {
        "language": "nl_NL", 
        "getExerciseTitle": "ExampleForStackOverflow",
        "Word": "ExampleForStackOverflow", 
        "Syllables":["Example", "Example1"]
    },
    {
        "Word": "SecondExampleForStackOverflow",
        "Syllables": ["Second", "Example"]
    }
]
   }
 };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/StackOverflowAccount/sa2eowhh/ I have a fiddle so you can see what I mean. When you click on the green + button it adds a whole field. This is a container that has an ID, I am trying to keep everything with the same ID with each other in the JSON file, so when I fetch it to my front-end it "knows" which syllables are part of the exercise word.

I have an ajax call which I think causes my JSON file to look like what I have right now.

my ajax call:

```
 function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {
$("#my_form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'saveJson.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: getUrlParameter('id'),
            formData: JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI($('#my_form').serialize()).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"') + '"}')
        },
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(response) {

    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your fiddle is not working, not found.

Second, if I understood it right you need to reformulate your JSON structure. I would suggest for you to create an array for your form data. Something like this:

```
{ "main_object": 
  {
    "id": "new",
     "formData": [
        {
            "language": "nl_NL", 
            "getExerciseTitle": "ExampleForStackOverflow",
            "Word": "ExampleForStackOverflow", 
            "Syllables":["Example", "Example1"]
        },
        {
            "Word": "SecondExampleForStackOverflow",
            "Syllables": ["Second", "Example"]
        }
    ]
 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I changed the link. It should work now :) would u mind by the way, if I were to use ur JSON structure as the example i'm looking for? Because this is exactly what I am looking for. How can I change the data structure with my ajax call anyway,  i'm pretty much a newbie in ajax so yeah, having a difficult time finding out how to change the database structure.

Comment: Feel free to use it.

Comment: Thanks you very much :)